# How do I position just one div below its parent, but keep the other divs in the same spot?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position

So, I'm creating a navigation bar, and I want the "Calculators" link to also have a dropdown menu when you hover over it. As you can see, it looks super weird when you hover over the calculators link. The links  "1st, 2nd, and 3rd option" for the dropdown menu appear side by side on the top for some reason, and because of that they change the position of the "Home" button. How can I make just the links appear below its parent div, and keeping everything else on the same line?

Here's the code. Hover over the "Calculators" button to see what I mean. How do those three links into a dropdown menu below the "Calculators" button.

```html
<body>
<div class = "menu"><div id = "icon">The Orange Calculator</div>
      <a id = "contact">Contact</a>
      <a id = "help">Help</a>
      <div style = "display: inline" class = "dropdown">
          <a class = "calc">Calculators</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <a id = "home">Home</a></div>
</body>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display:none;
}
.menu {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FF7800;
    //border-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, #FF7800, white);
    //border-image-slice: 1;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 17px; 
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 100px;
}
a {
    float: right;
    width: 12%;
    height: 100;
    text-align: center;
    color: #5F5F5F;
    transition: color 0.4s;
}
a:hover {
    color: #FF7800;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#home {
    background-color: #FF7800;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
}
#icon {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10;
    font-size: 35
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily align your drop down div using `position:absolute;` relative to its parent div `dropdown` and since you are using floats to adjust your elements I have also tried to achieve this using floats, but you can make this using css flexbox which is a far better approach. 
Please try the following css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 12%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown-content {
  visibility: Hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}
.dropdown a {
  float: none;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  margin: 4px 0;
}
.menu {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff7800;
  //border-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, #FF7800, white);
  //border-image-slice: 1;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 100px;
}
a {
  float: right;
  width: 12%;
  height: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: #5f5f5f;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}
a:hover {
  color: #ff7800;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#home {
  background-color: #ff7800;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
#icon {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10;
  font-size: 35;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div id="icon">The Orange Calculator</div>
    <a id="contact">Contact</a>
    <a id="help">Help</a>
    <div style="display: inline" class="dropdown">
      <a class="calc">Calculators</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a id="home">Home</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Almost what I wanted, but I also needed Link 3 to be below Link 2, which is below Link 1. How would I go about that?

Comment: Just change the css for `<a>` tags in `dropdown-content` to 
.dropdown-content a {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  margin:4px 0;
}

Comment: Thank you. This solution is exactly what I was looking for, I tried using flexbox but it seems to not work with links. Floats seem to work though.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use **flexbox** instead of **float**

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="header">
      <p>The Orange Calculator</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="link-navigation home">
        <a href="#" alt="home">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <p class="calc link-navigation">Calculators</p>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#" alt="link-1">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#" alt="link-2">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#" alt="link-3">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="link-navigation">
        <a href="#" alt="help">Help</a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-navigation">
        <a href="#" alt="contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.menu {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF7800;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.header, .header > p, .navbar, .dropdown, .link-navigation, .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
}
.link-navigation {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 50px 20px;
}
.link-navigation.home {
  background-color: #FF7800;
  color: #FFF;
}
.link-navigation > a, .dropdown-content > a {
  color: #5F5F5F;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header {
  margin: auto 0;
}
.header > p {
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-content > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}
a:hover, .calc:hover {
  color: #FF7800;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}
.home > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.dropdown > .calc.link-navigation {
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
</style>
```

You can read more about CSS Flexbox in [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)